# In a two column only junction table with compound PK, do I need another index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Consider the following:

tbl_Book

- BookID PK int identity(1,1)

tbl_Author

- AuthorID PK int identity(1,1)

tbl_BookAuthor

- BookID FK int
- AuthorID FK int

I have a composite/compound primary key on (BookID, AuthorID). More specifically, default values based on SSMS designer:

- Columns: (BookID ASC, AuthorID ASC)
- Is Unique: Yes
- Type: Primary Key
- Create As Clustered: Yes

At any point, would I need a non-clustered index on any one of the columns (BookID, AuthorID) or is it not relevant when it's only and will always be only those two columns in the table, as a composite key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only queries that run against this table specify both values of the composite key (or just the first value), then you need no other indexes.  The only time I can think you might want another index is if you had queries on just the second column in the compound key (and couldn't make that the first column because you also had queries on just that column as well).

Short answer: things should be fine as-is.

Comment: Thank you for this. A bit of reassurance was all that's needed. I suppose I can investigate down the road if performance is an issue, and add additional index at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a search on BookID would be an index seek

A search on AuthorID (without BookID)  would be an index scan

If you are never going to search on just the second then it would not matter

It seems like a search on Author only would be more likely so I would switch that order.

Comment: Is there an issue with re-ordering the columns within the composite key when there's a lot of data already there? Any potential issues?

Comment: The other side is more benefit if there is a lot of data.   Worse case you insert into a new table.